# How to find a model id and fields for an individual user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My models are setup as such User < Assignments > Course > Level > Step - in plain english a user take a course which creates an assigment, that assigment has many levels and many steps. 
I am trying to access the current step for the current user, so I can change a field in the database.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
  has_many :levels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :levels, allow_destroy: true
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps, allow_destroy: true
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level
end
```

My step model has a field called "state", which determines whether a step is completed or not for a user-  I am trying to access the "state" of a step for a current user,so I can change it or display it as I please.  In order to do this I need to obtain the current step for the user (not just the current step, as that will change the value for everyone) in my controller.

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController   
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def show
        @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
        @level = Level.find(params[:level_id])
        @step = Step.find(params[:id])
        @step_list = @level.steps
            // the above all work fine up to this point
        @assignment = Assignment.find(params["something goes here"])
        @user_step = @assignment.@course.@level.@step
    end

end
```

This, of course, does not work.  How would I write @user_step given the above information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, you can't do what you want to do with the models you currently have. Specifically, it's not sufficient (and probably not really meaningful) for your `Step` model to have a state field. If you need to keep track of state on a per-user-per-step basis, then you need a model which joins those two models and incorporates a state, such as:

```
def UserStep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :steps
end
```

You could then modify `User` and `Step` to have have a `has_many` relationship to this model. Within `StepsController#show`, you could then access `@step.user_steps` and select the `UserStep` for your logged in user, at which point you'd have access to the state.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a current_user? Then you probably should be able to do this:

```
course = current_user.courses.find(params[:course_id])
level = course.levels.find(params[:level_id])
step = level.steps.find(params[:id])

# Do something with the step ...
```

You don´t have to go through the Assignment model, it is just a join model that connects users and courses.